# How to access fragment in fragment from controller?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a view called "cutleryCustomerSearch" which includes (replace) a fragment:

```
<div id="content">
     <div th:replace="fragments/customerSearch :: customerSearch"></div>
</div>
```

in this fragment i have a table which i like to update via ajax:

```
<table id="customersTable" th:fragment="customersTable">
```

How do I have to set the return of my controller method which handles the ajax request? At the moment i have (DOES NOT WORK):

```
return "cutleryCustomerSearch :: customerSearch/customersTable";
```

But it does not set the content, it just deletes the table. 
It just works fine till i fragmentize the "customerSearch".

Here my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        cache   : false,
        url     : form.attr('action'),
        data    : form.serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            $("#customersTable").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is so easy...

```
return "fragments/customerSearch :: customersTable";
```

Comment: How to return multiple fragments from same page? i.e customersTable AND customersRule

Answer (score 5):

I found an example in this blog post : [Thymeleaf integration with Spring (Part 2)](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/thymeleaf-integration-with-spring-part-2.html).

A Spring MVC's [Controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller) will return the string `"results :: resultsList"`, like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/guests", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showGuestList(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("guests", hotelService.getGuestsList());
    return "results :: resultsList";
}
```

In the page "results" there will be a block (fragment) named "resultsList", like in this example :

```
<div th:fragment="resultsList" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(guests)}" class="results-block">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th th:text="#{results.guest.id}">Id</th>
                <th th:text="#{results.guest.surname}">Surname</th>
                <th th:text="#{results.guest.name}">Name</th>
                <th th:text="#{results.guest.country}">Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="guest : ${guests}">
                <td th:text="${guest.id}">id</td>
                <td th:text="${guest.surname}">surname</td>
                <td th:text="${guest.name}">name</td>
                <td th:text="${guest.country}">country</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

It should help...