# An issue in loading a Thymeleaf fragment inside the controller, the fragment name is being returned

Tags: spring-boot, fragment, thymeleaf

Trying to manipulate a Thymeleaf fragment inside a Java Spring Boot Controller. 
According to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461283/how-to-access-fragment-in-fragment-from-controller), in order to load the content of the Thymeleaf fragment inside the controller, all we need to do is the following

```
return "fragments/customerSearch :: customersTable";
```

While in my case, the following script results in only the String: "fragments/customerSearch :: customersTable" returned:

```
private String getDocumentsByTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    return "fragments/block-document :: popup(transaction)";
}
```

inside another function:

```
...
String documents = getDocumentsByTransaction(transaction);
...
```

Is there anything missing to load the content of the fragment instead of the fragment name as a static string?

Answer (score 0):

`return "fragments/customerSearch :: customersTable";` only works if the method is actually a controller method, and you're going through the entire MVC process.

In your example case, it should look like this:

```
@Controller
public class WhateverController {
    @GetMapping("/page")
    private String getDocumentsByTransaction() {
        return "fragments/block-document :: popup";
    }
}
```

Now if you access /page *in your browser*, it will return a fragment rather than an entire page.  You also can't just call `getDocumentsByTransaction()` in your java...  There is a lot of spring happening in the background.  If you really wanted to do something like that, you'd have to make an http request in your java.

Comment: Thank you, But isn't there anyway to load the fragment content and handle it inside a Java variable?

Comment: In terms of how thymeleaf is supposed to be used... manipulation of html fragments in a controller is a bit weird.  I supposed you could configure another TemplateEngine and execute the parser yourself.  Something like this: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html#executing-the-template-engine but this isn't something I would recommend.